# No mention of ARM versions of Lubuntu .. on the main website?

Tags: arm

Just a question for the Lubuntu team really -

I am a huge fan of Lubuntu  -  thank you and congratulations on creating a great distribution.

I am just surprised to notice that,  the main website  **doesn't mention that there are ARM versions**  - or provide any links to download.

Is that because they are 'unofficial' in some sense ?    I am running Lubuntu 11.10 on an Allwinner A10 device (the MK802) and it works a treat.

Don't "hide your light" guys - tell the world Lubuntu is a cracking OS for ARM systems.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it takes time and effort to maintain a distro on any given platform, and making it publicly available on that platform without someone willing to take ownership of it would be irresponsible. If you require LXDE on ARM and prefer an Ubuntu variant then I recommend you install Ubuntu for now, opting to install LXDE so that it is available from first boot.